# Can a vortex be self-sustaining?

Tags: spacetime, vortex

Can vortices be self-sustaining?

I suppose vortices in water are not self sustaining, since they need constant supply of water at speed i.e. kinetic energy. But is the same case applicable to space time vortices? like wormholes?? or do they need some energy source for sustenance?

Please try to give a intuitive explanation.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge *"space time vortices"* is not physics, but rather science fiction (I'm reminder of Ford trying to get Arthur to talk straight about eddys in the space time continuum, but that's another matter). I'm not going to close this yet on the chance that one of our resident relativists will come along and tell me I'm ignorant, but failing that...

Comment: I won't be waiting -- spacetime vortex is a term from SciFi. If you want to ask about wormholes, do it, but don't expect that when someone is calling something vortex it will automatically make it behave like a vortex.

Answer (score 4):

Self-sustaining vortices without dissipation (energy loss) are possible in superfluids (like, e.g., liquid helium) because there is no internal friction (viscosity) for the superfluid component. Rotation goes on by inertia. This is as close a I can imagine to a "self-sustaining vortex" although admittedly has little to do with space-time.

Comment: Now, I don't know whether there is any sort of resistive forces which can prevent fluidity of spacetime.

Comment: @Vineet: one need to define "fluidity of spacetime" first. Same goes for "spacetime vortex".